# Is there a lazyload jquery plugin with success and failure callbacks?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I want to archive something like this:

```
$(this).lazyload({
            effect : 'fadeIn',
            success : function(){
                // Callback here
            },
            failure : function(){
                // Callback here
            }
        });
```

Are there any jquery plugin can archive this?

Comment: haven't you read that plugin's documentation ?

Comment: which one? I found tons of lazyload plugins but have not idea which one have it.

Comment: well, you may search for verified plugins which provides a full document of what there plugin is for and what features it provide. And as you said that there are many lazyload plugins so we also can't tell you how is it possible and you also have told us about the plugin you are using

Comment: @AspiringAqib the question is _which_ lazyload plugin supports that.

Comment: I am not using any of them, because I cannot find the one that suits me.

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah thats right!

Comment: IDTS you may need to make your own.  I searched a little though. If you say i can help a little.